# Javascript to validate a dropdown menu dependent by date

Tags: javascript, forms, validation

I kindly ask if there is someone who could be so kind to write a validation code for my form.

I have a field with a calendar called "arrivaldate" and than a dropdown with the following items that could be for example some offers:

- none
- white offer
- black offer

The white offer is only valid when "arrivaldate" is between 1st and 25 April

The black offer is only valid when "arrivaldate" is between 20 April to 15 May

So in case the user push the "Send" button with the "white offer" selected and the "arrival date" selected in a date different from 1 to 25 April, the validation give the error "This offer is not valid for the selected period".

I really appreciate your kind help since now, and I thank you in advance.

Kind Regards

Filippo

Comment: this isn't free-code.com I'm afraid

Comment: http://www.rent-acoder.com/

Comment: Nice to-do list, what have you tried so far?

Comment: hi Filippo and welcome to StackOverflow. To create a good question that will be accepted by the comunity consider checking out the [Help Center Article](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) about that topic

Comment: Flagged as off-topic: too broad.

Answer (score 0):

Please Try this,

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.6.4/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link id="bsdp-css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.6.4/css/bootstrap-datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $('#arrivaldate').datepicker({
            format: 'yyyy/mm/dd'
        });

        $("#btn").on('click',function(){
            var arrival_date = $('#arrivaldate').val();
            var offer = $('#offer').val();
            var dateArrival = new Date(arrival_date);
            if(arrival_date=='' || offer==''){
                alert('please fill the fields');
            }
            if(offer == '1'){
                if(dateArrival <= new Date('2016-04-01') || dateArrival >= new Date('2016-04-25') ){
                    alert('White Offer Not Valid');
                }else{
                    alert('White Offer Valid');
                }
            }else if(offer == '2' && arrival_date!=''){
                if(dateArrival <= new Date('2016-04-20') || dateArrival >= new Date('2016-05-15') ){
                    alert('Black Offer Not Valid');
                }else{
                    alert('Black Offer Valid');
                }
            }
        });
    });
</script>

<form id="demoform">
    <div>
        Arrival Date: <input type="text" id="arrivaldate" class="form-control" data-provide="datepicker" style="width:200px"/>
    </div>
    <br/>
    <div>
        Offers:
        <select id="offer" class="form-control" style="width:200px">
            <option value="0">None</option>
            <option value="1">White Offer</option>
            <option value="2">Black Offer</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <br/>
    <div>
        <button class="btn btn-info" type="button" id="btn">Submit</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Why write code for the OP? In this case, it's better if the OP did it themselves rather than being spoon fed code.

Comment: Actually I'm new at Stackoverflow, It's my second day at stackoverflow, I don't know much about, next time I will take care of it. @evolutionxbox